# Generating single string on mysql MONTH in cakephp 3

Tags: mysql, cakephp-3.0

I am wanting to show current month data. But when I am using this query,        then generating extra single string from query.

```
$queryCurentMonth = $this->Bookings->find('all')
                ->where(["MONTH(Bookings.created)" => "MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())"]);
```

Generating :

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  `bookings` `Bookings` 
WHERE 
  MONTH(`Bookings`.`created`) = 'MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())'
```

This  = `'MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())'` , it is generating blank data.  How we can perfect this query.

Comment: you can simply do `["MONTH(Bookings.created) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())"]`

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is treating your RHS value as string in

```
MONTH(`Bookings`.`created`) = 'MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())'
```

'MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())' shouldn't have single quotes around it. Instead it should be like this

```
MONTH(`Bookings`.`created`) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
```

Try to compare year also as function MONTH() returns only a number 1 through 12, the query would return all records for a Month of all years, rather than only the current year. Use both MONTH(), YEAR() to compare months for the current year.

```
MONTH(`Bookings`.`created`) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(`Bookings`.`created`) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have got a solution. it is working finely now.

```
$queryCurentMonth = $this->Bookings->find('all')
                ->where(["MONTH(Bookings.created)" => date("m")]);
```